# Compilation error on include with ljpeg library in C

Tags: c, gcc, include, libjpeg

I have a project for college, where i need to use libjpeg (C language), to complete 2 codes the teacher gave to us. It's a about transforming a pic into ASCII symbols (like the ASCII draws, you know)

We have a code for reading a jpg and a code for writing a jpg.

The problem is i had to install the libjpeg, i THINK the installation went well but i'm not sure so i have 2 questions

1. How can i verify libjpeg is correctly installed ? i didn't link it to gcc so i have to use the option for saying to gcc where is jpeg-6b (the folder which contains ljpeg) so i tried this :

   Typing "`gcc -L/jpeg-6b`" the folder is *jpeg-6b* and it's right on the location where i do the command. i only get an error message about the fact the input is empty (normal ok), i think if the lib was not correctly installed, i should get an error for saying me i can't use the libjpeg version, right ?
2. In the 2 codes i said the teacher gave to us, she puts `#include <libjpeg>` on the beginning of it. But i saw on the internet that people use `#include <jpeglib.h>`, but both of them DON'T work and i get a message telling me :

   ```
   test.c:1:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: no such file or directory
    #include <jpeglib.h>
   ```

   is my include bad? or is the `libjpeg` bad installed ? (i read the doc and i did `./configure` then make like it's said)

Comment: I doubt that `/jpeg-6b` is the actual directory that the library is installed in. Please confirm that. "if the lib was not correctly installed, i should get an error for saying me i can't use the libjpeg version, right." No that's not right. If the command line is incomplete it will not even try to look for the library. You need something like `gcc -L<full_path_to_libjpeg> -ljpeg my_program.c`

Comment: ahh okay i put the link to the folder that contains the sources of the files
how can i find the directory where my lib got installed ?

Comment: Please post the full `./configure` command, then whether you did `make install` or not!

Comment: yes i did, it's in the documentation :
http://pastebin.com/1kwkx635
i did exactly this
but do i need to do something more ?

the full doc is here : http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/ (in the zip, there is an install.txt file)

Comment: and i saw there is some options for configuring it on pages 2 and 3 but are they optionnal or do I need to choose some of theses ? (i use Xubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you add `-L/jpeg-6b` you need `-I/jpeg-6b/path/to/jpeg/headers` too. I would recommend a `Makefile` to automate this.

Comment: i just tried this but it's the same
i typed :
gcc -L/jpeg-6b -I/jpeg-6b/ test.c

EDIT :  it seems my adress to the folder is not correct (see my comment above)
where can i find the directory where the external libraries are installed ?

Comment: Maybe `-Ljpeg-6b/lib -Ijpeg-6b/include`? What was the exact configure command you used?

Comment: Your library is not installed! It's just there somewhere on the file system, you just have to tell the compiler where, and do it correctly.

Comment: it isn't ? i did exactly what is said in the documentation: 
http://pastebin.com/1kwkx635
do i have to do something more than the ./configure and the make ; make test ?

the full doc is here : http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/ (in the zip, there is an install.txt file)
i did what is said about installing it

Comment: and i saw there is some options for configuring it on pages 2 and 3 but are they optionnal or do I need to choose some of theses ? (i use Xubuntu)

Comment: If you use *Xubuntu* (BTW good for you, it's nice that someone loves XFCE and it makes sense), then just `apt-get install libjpeg-devel` or something similar, to determine which one just `apt-cache search jpeg | grep devel`. Then after that I thing `jpeg.h` is the header not `jpeglib.h` or something like that, and `-ljpeg` should work automatically.

Comment: yea XFCe is more ergonomic imo
so since libjpeg-devel doesn't exists, i did the apt-cache command but i never did that before so i prefer asking before installing something i relevant, i have this : 
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/730797screen2.png
i think the first one should be the right one, isn't it ?
but will it allow me to use the libjpeg ? (sry i'm really a newbie in C, i try to search on google as much as i can but i don't always find answers)

Comment: None of them seem to be! It should be `jpeg8-devel` or something. Sorry I don't use any debian based distro but Fedora.

Comment: I just checked it, it's because on debian base distros the suffix for development packages is `-dev` instead of `-devel` which is on RedHat based ones like Fedora, the package is apparently `libjpeg8-dev`.

Comment: thanks ! i tried this, it installed well but now when i compile a simple hello world with #include <jpeglib.h>, i have some compilation errors that come from the library itself ... ? wtf ? (never get that before)
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/254905screen2.png
I think it's almost working but it is not really usable for now, how can I fix this ?

Comment: UPDATE : IT'S OKAY EVERYTHING WORKS WELL i just had to include stdlib and stdio and it compiled ! :) thanks a lot from your help mate